# posterior - many data points as well as one?

Tags: posterior

I used to thinking of the posterior as being the probability distribution over parameters consistent with *a particular* data point,
$$
  p(\theta|x) \propto p(x|\theta) p(\theta)
$$
where $x$ is some *particular* data point (not many).

But in sequential updating, the posterior serves as the new prior after seeing some arbitrary number of data, and in some way it is summarizing all the points seen so far.

So, is it correct to think of the posterior as applying *either* to one point,
or to a *subgroup* of points?

Is there a different name for these cases?

Comment: $x$ can represent a vector of points of length $k$, and $k$ can be $1$ or $2$ or $738$ or anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the sequential updating is done in Bayesian framework. When you obtain more points your likelihood will be:
$p(x_1,..x_n|\theta)$ and the posterior be $p(\theta| x_1,..x_n)$